# Alamofire not creating autnentication header to send credentials

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm attempting to access an api using my username and api key. An example they give, which I believe is .NET, is:

```
Public Sub GET_Products()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.ssactivewear.com/v2/products/?style=39")
    
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("YOurCustomerNumber", "YourAPIKey")
    
    Try
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Dim StreamReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Result = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
        If response.StatusCode = HtppStatusCode.OK Then
            Products = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Sku))(Result)
        Else
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I've used the following to test the request for a response:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.ssactivewear.com/v2/products/") else { return }

let username = "myusername"
let password = "myapikey"
AF.request(url).authenticate(username: username, password: password).responseJSON { response in
      print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
      print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")
      print("HeaderFields: \(String(describing: response.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields))")
    
      if let json = response.value {
          print("JSON: \(json)")
          //self.responseText.text = "JSON: \(json)"
      }
      
      if let error = response.error {
          print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          //self.responseText.text = "ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)"
      }
  }
```

This fails authentication because no authentication header is sent. I believe I read this is expected behavior but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

create APIMiddle class:

```
class APIManager
{
   class func headers() -> HTTPHeaders
   {
       let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "application/json"
       ]
    
       return headers
    }
}
```

your api call:

```
let request = AF.request(path, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: APIManager.headers(), interceptor: nil)   
    request.responseDecodable(of: UserModel?.self) {(resposnse) in
        
        let user = resposnse.value
        print(user)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire's `authenticate` method adds a `URLCredential` to the `Request` which is used to respond to server challenges. If the server never sends a challenge for those credentials, the credentials will never be used. `api.ssactivewear.com` appears to use HTTP Basic auth, which should work fine, but I couldn't find any specific documentation about that. There may be other requirements to properly make a request to the API. I suggest you investigate those requirements as well as the actual network traffic being sent to see what's actually happening.